# USB sound card stops on Asus Windows 10 / works great on Lenovo Windows 7- wrong settings?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, usb, audio, windows-10

I have weird problem... It seems that on my personal laptop [Asus N73SM] after connecting the external sound card "musical fidelity v90-hpa" sound play nice, but after I pause the music, several seconds later I can hear quiet "click" sound, like when you turn on/off sound card. And then when I press play you hear click again. When I had Windows 7 installed sound was just coming back now with Windows 10 it does not.

I made several checks, different USB and different laptop - also Asus with Windows 10, same situation.

However when I brought the sound card to work and plugged it to Lenovo ThinkPad with Windows 7 Enterprise - it worked without the problem, moreover there was no card suspending - you didn't hear this click sound. It seems that my personal laptop has some usb settings which are causing the error.

I tried to turn off usb selective suspend, but that didn't help. Do you have suggestions which other settings I should change as well?

For example: pci express link state power management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: yes it is caused by PCI Express link state power management. Turn it off and all your USB sound cards (and probably other USB devices you might have problems with) will work correctly.